# How do I find the intersection of those two sets without using the in operator or any built-in functions. How do I solve this?

Tags: python-3.x

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = [1,3,5,6]
>>> list(set(a) & set(b))
[1, 3, 5]
```

Not allowed to use any operators or use any in-built functions like .intersect()  How do I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

If `a` and `b` are sorted and doesn't have duplicates, you can do:

```
i, j = 0, 0
intersection = []
while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] == b[j]:
        intersection.append(a[i])
        i += 1
        j += 1
    elif a[i] > b[j]:
        j += 1
    else:
        i += 1
print(intersection)
```

Here you start searching at the beginning of `a` and `b`. Since they are sorted if the element in `a[i]` is larger you should check the next element in `b`. If the element in `b[j]` is larger then you should check the next element in a. If they are equal this means you find an intersecting element and continue from the next elements of `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question correctly but from what I read this is a solution, sorted or otherwise.

```
def intersect(a,b):

    inters = []

    for num in a:
        for item in b:
            if num == item:
                inters.append(num)
    return inters
```